# Ubuntu 18.04 Login Shows Dialog Box vs. Greeter

Tags: 18.04

All,

I have been running Ubuntu for years and recently I noticed that the default greeter in Ubuntu 18.04 has changed to show a dialog box (See links below). I tried to reinstall GDM and the ubuntu-desktop package. I wanted to see if anyone has seen this issue and if there is a way to fix it. I also suspect it could be related to Wayland vs. Xorg which I still need to test.

[Example of Login Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiB3k.jpg)

[Example of Typical 18.04 Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsDX8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing this problem. I was testing the new communitheme and it was loading a CSS that had issues.

Option 1 - Remove the theme

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-communitheme-session
```

Option 2 - Change the CSS you are using with the following command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

You will be prompted to select an alternative select the path *"/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css"*

Reboot and it will be back to normal.

Comment: Better late than never . Thanks I came to the conclusion as well but I wish I would have checked back sooner. This was spot on and just wanted to acknowledge. Thanks for helping out.